# Error message System.IO.FileNotFoundException when connecting to an Excel sheet

Tags: c#, excel, database, linq, console

I am trying to fetch data from an Excel sheet via Linq for a console application.
However, I always get the error message that the file was not found, although I specified the correct path. (The File is on the Desktop)

I have already tried other examples on the internet (csharp.hotexamples.com), but I always get the same error message.
What could be the reason for this?

here my code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var excelpath = @"[Desktop...]\Employee.xlsx";
        var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(excelpath);
        excel.FileName = "Employee.xlsx";
        excel.AddMapping<Person>(x => x.Name, "Name");
        excel.AddMapping<Person>(x => x.Birthday, "Birthday");    

        var people = from e in excel.Worksheet<Person>("Name") select e;

        foreach (var item in people)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item.Name}, {item.Birthday}");
        }


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I put the file in the desktop location, I got the error message :'The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object '"Project location"\bin\Debug\Employee.xlsx'. and when I moved the location of the excel file to the bin folder, the error was gone and it seems that the process of what you did should be alright.

Comment: But unfortunately it still doesn't work. Thank you for trying.

Answer (score 0):

I followed your example (as shown in the question) when I was running into the same issue.  I was able to successfully connect after doing 3 things:

1. Make sure the excel file is not open
2. I added System.Data.OleDb to my project through NuGet PM
3. I took out the line to set .FileName property

This may not be a comprehensive solution, but it is working for me.  :-)

Sample Code:

```cs
            var excelpath = @"C:\Users\... myFile.xlsx";
            var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(excelpath);
            excel.AddMapping<ProjectDto>(x => x.ProjectName, "Project");

            var query1 = from x in excel.Worksheet<ProjectDto>("Projects") select x;

            List<string> projectNames = new List<string>();

            foreach (var result in query1)
            {
                projectNames.Add(result.ProjectName);
            }
```

Comment: If you still run into issues, try removing the DateTime property to see if it works and go from there, but that is just speculation, this library is new to me.  You may have to parse it from a string.  but again, pure speculation.

Comment: And make sure you are using correct 32 or 64 bit LinqToExcel, to match the bitness of your Excel App.